# How can I create a table where my inputs in one column spit out an assigned “code” for that text in another column?

Tags: python, excel, formula

I want to create a table that basically converts the text from one column into a specific code in another column. For example, I have a “rock type” column and a “geology code column”. If I type “SAND” into the rock type column then “401c” will appear in the geology code column.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use a dictionary as following:

```
conversions = {...} # add conversions as (rock type: geology code)
```

Then, given some rock type `rock_type`, the corresponding geology code can be given by `conversions[rock_type]`. For example, using your example, you can insert `converions["SAND"] = "401c"`. Then, later on, typing `conversions["SAND"]` will give `401c`.